# what is the difference between looping the div and making it as separate component and looping?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to know what's the difference between this code

```
     {this.state.products &&
                    this.state.products.map((product, index) => (
                      <div key={index}>
                        <Subd
                          name={product.name}
                          price={product.price}
                          info={product.info}
                          image={product.image}
                          handleShow={this.showProduct}
                          handleTotal={this.calculateTotal}
                        />
                      </div>
                    ))}
```

and looping the div inside `<Sudb/>` component like

```
this.state.products &&
        this.state.products.map((product, index) => (
      <div className="row form-group">
      <div className="col-sm-2">
        <img
          className="card-img-right flex-auto d-none d-lg-block"
          alt="Thumbnail+{index}"
          src={product.image}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        <h4>
          {product.name}: ${product.price}
        </h4>
        <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={this.showInfo}>
          show info
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-4 text-right">
        qty: {this.state.qty}
        <br />
        <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={this.add}>
          {" "}
          +1{" "}
        </button>
        <button
          className="btn btn-outline-primary"
          onClick={this.subtract}
          disabled={this.state.qty < 1}
        >
          {" "}
          -1{" "}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>`
```

in the above case if I update the quantity its affecting all the three objects but in the first case it's working fine. Can anyone explain what's the exact difference between both? Sandbox link [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-currying-m5des)

In the second code I have made `<Subd/>` component code directly

Answer (score 0):

The problem from what i can see in the code sample provided with the second sample provided is the following.

You are using the same piece of state for all products. so when you update this.state.qty for one row it updates all of them simultaneously.

The reason it does work when you separate it is because then each row has its own state that you can store individual quantities in.

If you did feel the need to not seperate out that code you could create an array on state for each of the qty's. and change up the subtract method to accept an index that it can use to access a certain rows qty state on the qty state array.

To pass in parameters to onclick you have to wrap it in a arrow function so it does not run automatically when the page mounts like so

`onClick={() => {someFunction(param)}`

Comment: Hi even in the second case I am having single common state as qty then why it's not working like the first case

Comment: The second case does not have a single common state for all rows. each row component has its own state, and methods to edit that state.
Look in your subIndex.js file that you are exporting the Subd component from.
Inside that components constructor you are initiating that components state with a object called qty.

Comment: it's a common declared state how it will get differentiated ?

Comment: If your referencing the fact they are named the same thing state is scoped to the component it is in naming two components states with the same properties wont do anything

Comment: my doubt is without mentioning the index value how each row maintains it's own state ie (qty) even when the state is common